# rxJava. Help to understand how publish and unsubscribe work

Tags: rx-java

I observe strange behavior when using `publish()` in conjunction with `observeOn` and `subscribeOn`. Please take a look at the folowing examples.

Code:

```
ConnectableObservable<String> observable = Observable.create(
    new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            int i=0;
            Log.d("testTag:", "start call");
            while (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext("item "+i);
                i++;
            }
            Log.d("testTag:", "completed");
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }
).publish();

observable
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(
        new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                Log.d("testTag:", "item received 1 : " + String.valueOf(s));
            }
        });

observable.connect();
```

Output:

```
start call
item received 1 : item 0
item received 1 : item 1
item received 1 : item 2
item received 1 : item 3
item received 1 : item 4
item received 1 : item 5
item received 1 : item 6
item received 1 : item 7
item received 1 : item 8
item received 1 : item 9
```

Condition `!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` never happens. This is totally fine. Strange thing happens when I add `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` and `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`. Take a look:

```
ConnectableObservable<String> observable = Observable.create(
    new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            int i=0;
            Log.d("testTag:", "start call");
            while (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext("item "+i);
                i++;
            }
            Log.d("testTag:", "completed");
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }
)
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.publish();

observable
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(
        new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                Log.d("testTag:", "item received 1 : " + String.valueOf(s));
            }
        });

observable.connect();
```

Output:

```
start call
item received 1 : item 0
item received 1 : item 1
item received 1 : item 2
item received 1 : item 3
item received 1 : item 4
item received 1 : item 5
item received 1 : item 6
item received 1 : item 7
item received 1 : item 8
item received 1 : item 9
completed
```

Please help me understand why condition `!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` become `true`.

PS. I understand that if I want check `!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` I should use `.publish().refCount()` instead of `connect()`. My goal is understand current behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publish()` reacts to 0 subscribers by consuming the source stream until completion (which never happens here). So once you took 10 with the sole subscribe(), the source will keep running forever or until you call `unsubscribe` on the `Subscription` returned by the connect() call.

In the second case, you get !subscriber.isUnsubscribed() true because you overflow the observeOn's or the publish's internal queue and the whole chain dies with `MissingBackpressureException`, which triggers an unsubscription that reaches your Observable eventually.

What you need is share() instead of just publish() so your source gets terminated if all subscribers go away, but note that since your Observable doesn't respect backpressure, you are still prone to `MissingBackpressureException`.

Generally, I suggest looking at standard operators and Observable factories first instead of rolling your Observable, or looking at `AbstractOnSubscribe` and the examples in its javadoc to see how to implement a backpressure-aware custom Observable.

Comment: It is a shame :( I filtered the log and did not see `MissingBackpressureException` :( Sorry for such dumb question. Thank you for your time!